# How to prevent the capture groups of this regex from overlapping so that they cannot capture the substrings correctly?

Tags: python, regex

```py
import re

input_text = "En esta alejada ciudad por la tarde circulan muchos camiones con aquellos acoplados rojos, grandes y bastante pesados, llevándolos por esos trayectos bastante empedrados, polvorientos, y un tanto arenosos. Y incluso bastante desde lejos ya se les puede ver." #example string

list_verbs_in_this_input = ["serías", "serían", "sería", "ser", "es", "llevándoles", "llevándole", "llevándolos", "llevándolo", "circularías", "circularía", "circulando", "circulan", "circula", "consiste", "consistían", "consistía", "consistió", "visualizar", "ver", "empolvarle", "empolvar", "verías", "vería", "vieron", "vió", "vio", "ver", "podrías" , "podría", "puede"]
exclude = rf"(?!\b(?:{'|'.join(list_verbs_in_this_input)})\b)"
direct_subject_modifiers, noun_pattern = exclude + r"\w+" , exclude + r"\w+"

modifier_connectors = r"(?:(?:a[úu]n|todav[íi]a|incluso)\s+|)\s*(?:de|)\s*(?:gran|bastante\s*(?:m[áa]s|menos|)|(?:un\s*(?:tanto|poco)|)\s*(?:m[áa]s|menos)|)" #its occurrence is optional

#enumeration_of_noun_modifiers = direct_subject_modifiers + "(?:" + modifier_connectors  + direct_subject_modifiers + "){2,}"
enumeration_of_noun_modifiers = r"(?:" + "(?:(?:,\s*|)y|,)\s*" + modifier_connectors + r"\s*" + direct_subject_modifiers + r"\s*" + r")*"

#sentence_capture_pattern = r"(?:aquellas|aquellos|aquella|aquel|los|las|el|la|esos|esas|este|ese|otros|otras|otro|otra)\s+" + noun_pattern + r"\s+" + enumeration_of_noun_modifiers
sentence_capture_pattern = r"(?:aquellas|aquellos|aquella|aquel|los|las|el|la|esos|esas|este|ese|otros|otras|otro|otra)\s+" + noun_pattern + r"\s+" + modifier_connectors + r"\s+" + direct_subject_modifiers + r"\s+" + r"(?:" + enumeration_of_noun_modifiers + r"|)"

input_text = re.sub(sentence_capture_pattern, r"((NOUN)'\g<0>')", input_text, flags=re.I|re.U)
print(repr(input_text)) # --> output
```

This pattern manages to make some captures only when in the pattern in `sentence_capture_pattern` change `r"\s+"` to `r"\s*"`. I think it's a problem where the substrings that the capturing groups should capture "overlap", although I'm not sure how to avoid that.

The mechanism that the capture groups must follow to assign the identified information should be the following:

[image]

Note that what should always capture the pattern stored in the `modifier_connectors` variable is totally optional, since it may or may not appear.

In this case, this type of coincidence occurs 2 times, although it could occur more, so it performs 2 information reorganizations. So you get this **correct output** string:

```
"En esta alejada ciudad por la tarde circulan muchos camiones con ((NOUN)'aquellos acoplados rojos, grandes y bastante pesados'), llevándolos por ((NOUN)'esos trayectos bastante empedrados, polvorientos, y un tanto arenosos'). Y incluso bastante desde lejos ya se les puede ver."
```

Comment: I suggest using NLTK package here, using Spanish as the language pack.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am not using NLTK, but to tokenize I am using spacy, in fact I put the list of verbs `list_verbs_in_this_input` here to simplify the question, but they are verbs detected by spacy. However, if you mean using NLTK to detect the entire capture stream, I'm not quite sure how to do that. I was using regex because beyond the complexity of the problem, it is still a defined pattern to perform a search (which repeats the final part, but always maintaining a repetitive sequence), and after performing that search, use the `re.sub()` function